# How to extend property on interface

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I have two interfaces. Interface `A` is the generic interface, while Interface `B` is a special extension that is less used.

```
export interface A {
  foo: {
    bar1: any;
    bar2: any;
  } 
}

export interface B extends A {
  foo: {
    bar3: any;
  }
  specialBar: Function
}
```

How can I make it so that `B.foo` inherits the properties on `A.foo ('bar1', 'bar2')` while also extending `B.foo` to include a new property `('bar3')`?

Is there a way to extend `A.foo` without giving `A.foo` an interface of its own?

Currently, WebStorm is throwing the error: `Incompatible override for member from interface A`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
export interface A {
  foo: {
    bar1: any;
    bar2: any;
  } 
}

export interface B extends A {
  foo: A['foo'] & {
    bar3: any;
  }
  specialBar: Function
}
```

`A['foo']` is a [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) and `&` is an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types) and together they express that `B.foo` should be of the same type of `A.foo` plus all the new properties defined in `B.foo`, which is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you're really looking for, but there's this hack:

```
const _a = undefined as A

export interface B extends A {
  foo: typeof _a.foo & {
    bar3: any;
  }
  specialBar: Function
}
```